# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a website using **ReactJS**. And when I run I got "**Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.**" error.

Here is my code:

```
  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [server, setServer] = useState({});
  const [discord, setDiscord] = useState({});
  const [memberCounter, setMemberCounter] = useState(false);
  const [emojiCounter, setEmojiCounter] = useState(false);
  const [roleCounter, setRoleCounter] = useState(false);
  const [boostCounter, setBoostCounter] = useState(false);

  const { id, type } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/serverinfo/' + id)
      .then(res => {
        if(res.ok) return res.json();
      })
      .then(res => {
        setLoad(true);
        setData(res);
        setServer(res._doc);
        setDiscord(res.discord);
      })
  }, []);

  if(server.counter && server.counter.length > 0){
    server.counter.map(c => {
      if(c.type == "members") setMemberCounter(true);
      if(c.type == "roles") setRoleCounter(true);
      if(c.type == "emojis") setEmojiCounter(true);
      if(c.type == "boosts") setBoostCounter(true);
    });
  }
```

And it says I have an error on this line
`setServer(res._doc);`

Any ideas what's the problem?

**UPDATE**

For those who has this issue, you just need to put `setMemberCounter(true);, setRoleCounter(true);, setEmojiCounter(true);, setBoostCounter(true);` these inside `useEffect()`.